# Getting incorrect results when calculating difference between two times

Tags: java, time, simpledateformat

I am working on an android app to keep track of hours between signing in and out.
An employee can sign in one day and sign out the next day or within the same day.

Within the app, I have a function that should calculate the difference between two times.

But I am not getting the correct results...

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mma");

    Date start;
    Date end;
    double difference;

    //Test 1
    start = simpleDateFormat.parse("7:00AM");
    end = simpleDateFormat.parse("3:30PM");
    difference = end.getTime() - start.getTime();
    Log.d("difference", String.valueOf(difference)); // 3.06E7
    Log.d("Time difference", String.valueOf(((difference/1000)/60)/60));
    //Prints '8.5' correct.

    // Text 2
    start = simpleDateFormat.parse("11:00PM");
    end = simpleDateFormat.parse("7:30AM");
    difference = end.getTime() - start.getTime();
    Log.d("difference2", String.valueOf(difference)); // -5.58E7
    Log.d("Time difference2", String.valueOf(((difference/1000)/60)/60));
    //Prints '-15.5' but should print '8.5'
```

As you can see... the first test works correctly, yet the second test fails. 
How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: A `long / long` will always return a `long`.  Meaning that there are no decimal places.  You must cast one of the values to a `float` or `double` first.

Comment: @Powerlord I made your recommended changes, and am getting answers with decimals, ty. But as you can see in my code sample's comments that 'Test 2' is still printing an incorrect value.

Comment: have a look at `System.out.println(difference);`

Comment: @ScaryWombat I added two lines to print the value of 'difference', please see the code sample. Its not much help to me.

Comment: if end is less than start you need to do two sums (12 - 11) + (7:30 - 0)

Comment: @ScaryWombat can you please elaborate?

Comment: You want the time between 11PM and midnight and then the time between midnight and 07:30AM  - although I think you are better of using Calendar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current issue is that your are calculating the difference between two hours and these hours are technically on the same day.

You are currently calculating the time difference between `(A) Day 1: 23:00` and `(b) Day 1: 7:30`. 7:30 is 15.5 hours before 23:00.

You will need to add your starting and ending dates.

Exemple:

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");

Date day1 = simpleDateFormat.parse("12/10/2017 23:00:00");
Date day2 = simpleDateFormat.parse("13/10/2017 07:30:00");

DateTime dt1 = new DateTime(day1);
DateTime dt2 = new DateTime(day2);

System.out.print(Hours.hoursBetween(dt1, dt2).getHours() % 24 + " hours, ");
System.out.print(Minutes.minutesBetween(dt1, dt2).getMinutes() % 60 + " minutes.");
// Should print "8 hours, 30 minutes.'
```

Answer (score 1):

`start` is after `end` (on same day), hence a negative result; `-15.5 + 24 == 8.5`. A modulo 24 is in order:

```
difference = end.getTime() - start.getTime();
difference = difference/1000/60/60;
if (difference < 0) {
    difference += 24;
}
Log.d("Time difference", String.valueOf(difference));
```